# fgets loop ending with EOF skips next fgets

Tags: c, input, fgets, eof

I'm trying to get a user input after an undefined amount of another input done. But the problem is that the second `fgets` after the while loop never gets invoked. I'm ending the loop with `EOF`, maybe that's the error. But I don't know how else I should end the loop.

Another funny thing is: It's a task from my C coding class and the lecturer has a video of her solution, and if I'm copying her code 1:1, it also does not work. It also skips the second `fgets` call.

I've already cut down the code to an absolute bare minimum to get the error, but as you can see: a few lines of code and it does not work. I even tried debugging it with GDB, but I can't figure out how to have it behave like it does in the video.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char input[80];
    while (fgets(input, 80, stdin) != NULL) {
        // nop
    }
    fgets(input, 80, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your analyse seems correct to me. Since the while loop will only stop when no more input will be available, the next call to `fgets()` will not give anything.

Comment: But as I said: The code of my lecturer works in her video fine, but not on my machine. I can only imagine that she doen't stop it with EOF, but what else? I can only hear her pressing a key or a key combination on her keyboard.

Comment: *"... after an undefined amount of another input done. "* - something *must* define when to stop reading data. The posted code defines that 'something' as being when `input` reaches an error or eof state. That same state is still present in the subsequent `fgets` (whose return value you're inconveniently ignoring, but would tell you it didn't work if you actually retained and examined it).

Comment: It's just a sample code that represents the idea of the problem. I've made a mistake, originally the code was while(fgets(input, 80, stdin) != NULL). That's also exactly the line that my lecturer has. And the solution can't be that I should change it. It does work for her without problems. And if you say an EOF is still present at the second fgets, then there is another way to end this while loop without EOF and that's what I need to know

Comment: There could be a `break;` statement in the `while()` loop.

Comment: That's not a solution. That's simply ignoring the Problem.

Comment: What do you mean by `EOF`?

Comment: Since you use Linux, you can shed light on the matter with `strace -eread your_program`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I got the problem! Found out that on every OS that the code worked, libc was in version 2.27. On all other systems libc was in version 2.29. So I compiled the code with the `-static` option on a libc-2.27 System and copied it to my main system with libc-2.29 and everything worked as inspected! 
So now I just have to figure out, how to downgrade my libc to 2.27 on Manjaro.

Edit: Got a mail from the developers. They say the way it behaves on my system is the correct way and linked to commit 2cc7bad0ae. So apparently my lecturer used a bug for her solution.

Answer (score 1):

when you press ctrl+d = EOF in mac (on windows its the same i guess) for the first time you had to exit the while loop.

when you press it again the fgets after the loop works and it prints the last line.

sorry for my english :)

Comment: When I press ^D the programm instantly prints. The second fgets() get's skipped. That's the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

for LINUX and UNIX systems it's ctrl +D and ctrl + z for windows. you can test it out using the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char input[80], input1[50];
    while (fgets(input, 80, stdin) != NULL) {
        // nop
    }   
        fgets(input1, 50, stdin);
    printf("input is %s\n", input);
        printf("input1 is %s\n", input1);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, mention your system in the post for further clarification

Comment: It's Manjaro Linux and your code does not work on my System. As soon as I press ^D, it instantly prints the first and the second is just giberish what was found in the memory.